# How to create table in the bigquery from the bigquery-public-data

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to locate a guild that shows how to get the dataset from bigquery-public-data to a table under my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
select * from dataset.tablename
```

using this query your could create a table under your project name and dataset.